# How can I improve performance when using jQuery Searchable Select plugin (it is very slow when initialising a large number of selects)

Tags: jquery, performance, jquery-plugins, drop-down-menu, searchable

I am using the jQuery searchable select plugin http://effinroot.eiremedia.netdna-cdn.com/repo/plugins/forms-controls/searchabledropdown/index.html

This works fine if I have a small number of selects on a page however I have a large number (can be several 100 on one page). When I initialise the plugin (either by class or looping through the IDs) it takes a long time (~10 seconds) and consumes all the system resources.

It is when I run the setup code I get the problem, for example:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $("select").searchable();
});
```

The selects I have are actually the same two repeated many times. I have tried initialising with one select (which is much quicker) and copying then copying that (both by HTML and jQuery clone()), but the copied instances aren't searchable.

Is there anyway to reduce the time it takes to initialise the plugin for large numbers or repeating selects?

Comment: I would recomment to write your own javascript instead of jquery methods in performance-sensible cases. In spite of the fact it consumes much more time, you achive control on everything and you can write a code which is optimized for your certain situation.

Comment: MY question would be - Why do you have SO MANY selects on one page? I would say you potentially have a UI issue. Is there any way you can change the way your site works?

Comment: The site is a table of activities and the drop downs are owners of the activities (to allow reallocation) - so the decision to have a lot of selects is deliberate (as we allow the user to have all items on one page if they wish and them filter to what they want).

Comment: I understand the point about write your own - however we're just prototyping just now so was trying to find a nice cross browser solution which we could implement quickly - obviously if we can't get it tuned we'll have to go that way.

Answer (score 1):

Are you passing withDataAndEvents as true when calling clone?  I think .clone(true) should work.  Make sure you clone after the select you're cloning has been made searchable.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var clone_src = $('#originalSelectUser');
    $(clone_src).searchable({        });
    $(".dest").each(function(i) {
        $(clone_src).clone(true).attr('id', 'clone'+i).appendTo('#enddiv');
    });  
});
```

Another idea might be to make the two that you need, only hidden.  Then, when a select is focused on, swap it with a clone of the matching hidden select.  If the clone isn't working you may need to initialize it with a .searchable() call after cloning, but you shouldn't have to.

Comment: I hadn't tried with withDataAndEvents (I'll try that and see how it goes). Thanks

Comment: Hi - thanks. Using withDataAndEvents does indeed clone the whole thing, however it still references the original locations, so jumps back to the original - see here for example: http://jsfiddle.net/XdjRx/  Any idea how to update the references?

Comment: When you clone something with an ID you'll need to change the ID of the clone or you'll get errors/conflicts.   See here: http://jsfiddle.net/nathanlounds/6bMWr/1/ for my fixed example.

Comment: Thanks-but that doesn't quite work. The problem is I'm not just cloning the select, I'm also cloning the events associated with it - and unfortunately that's where my knowledge is letting me down as I'm not sure how these work. You'll see from the first JSfiddle (above) then when you click on the cloned item, the search box is generated for the first (interestingly if I just move it and don't clone it works fine). If you check here-even when updating the ID it still doesn't work- http://jsfiddle.net/XdjRx/2/  You will see in the example you posted that the cloned search boxes aren't searchable

Comment: There was a typo that I fixed, but it didn't save for some reason.  Here's a version with the typo fixed.  http://jsfiddle.net/6bMWr/5/

Comment: Your problems are still because you're breaking the 'no duplicate ids' rule.  When you clone #startdiv, you end up with two items with that id.  You also get two elements with the id #originalSelect.  You should clone the orignalSelect, not the div containing it.  You should immediately change the id.  The way you do it you actually change the ID of the first one, not the clone.  Take another look at my fixed version.  There was a typo (.. should have been .) that I've fixed here:  http://jsfiddle.net/6bMWr/5/

Comment: I need to clone the div as the plugin creates some addition items. Check your demo and you will see the cloned versions are not searchable - they are just selects. (click in the first one and start typing, now try the same with the clones)

Comment: `$(document).ready(function() {
    var clone_src = $('#originalSelectUser');
    $(clone_src).searchable({        });
    $(".dest").each(function(i) {
        $(clone_src).clone(true).attr('id', 'clone'+i).appendTo('#enddiv').searchable({        });
    });  
});`